# Can't retrieve entity config: admin/permission_variable

Tags: magento

i am not able to open my `System->Permission->Variable && System->Permission->Blocks` in magento admin area, i am facing this issue since i was updated latest patch. i am getting below error on page.

There has been an error processing your request

Can't retrieve entity config: `admin/permission_variable`

Trace:

> /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(282): Mage::throwException('Can't retrieve ...')
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(284): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getTableName('admin/permissio...')
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(247): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getTable('permission_vari...')
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(155): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getMainTable()
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(192): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getMainTable()
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(135): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->_initSelect()
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1354): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Array)
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1386): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('admin_resource/...', Array)
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('admin/variable_...', Array)
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php(54): Mage::getResourceModel('admin/variable_...')
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_Variable_Grid->_prepareCollection()
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
>   /home1/dcorzcom/public_html/dcorzdev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home1/dcorzcom...')

Comment: Anybody have any solution  please?

Comment: anyone have any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

From https://magentary.com/kb/cms-pages-transactional-emails-broken-after-supee-6788-patch/

The Update-SQL-Script had the wrong permission. Magento have to execute the script, with manual upload the script had the wrong permissions. now everything is fine.

Im not sure I understand the answer myself, but maybe someone else can help from here

I turned my cache off, and then was able to access.  Then turn it back on.  Like flushing it

Answer (score 0):

Issue is after After update patch/Magento you need to do cache refresh and  compilation disable.